# Integration Applovin Sdk in unity android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, integration, applovin

I integrate applovin SDK in unity android but I get this error when it run on an Android device:

> ERROR :UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.applovin.sdk.unity.AppLovinFacade

Here is my code :

```
public class ApplovinHandler : MonoBehaviour {
    public  Text logtxt;
    void Awake () {
        try{
        AppLovin.InitializeSdk ();
        AppLovin.SetTestAdsEnabled ("true");
        AppLovin.SetUnityAdListener ("ApplovinHandler");
        ShowBanner ();
        }catch(Exception e){
            logtxt.text += e + "/n";
        }
    }
    public void ShowBanner ()
    {
        logtxt.text = "Show banner ads"; 
    AppLovin.ShowAD(AppLovin.AD_POSITION_CENTER,AppLovin.AD_POSITION_BOTTOM);

    }
```

Comment: when do you call it? Provide us your code

Comment: hey @jackjop you  can see my code now  thanks for asking:) any solution ?

Comment: are you including the package to the bundle? Can you follow [this guide](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ads-implementation-unity-using-applovin)? It shouldn't give you this error.

Comment: Latest version of applovin SDK require Google Play service sdk without this applovin sdk not working when i export my game to Android studio then it run successfully in device and without play service sdk it showing error in logcat and  when i run a game on device in unity then it show that error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to run AppLovin on Android Unity, not only do you need their Android SDK JAR, you also need their Android Unity Bridging JAR. You can get it from their Unity Plugin [here](https://dash.applovin.com/integration#androidIntegration).